# Sorting Through NSData Results

Tags: ios, nsdata, spotify

I use a Web API from Spotify in my app to find a track by a particular artist within Spotify.  The results look like this:

```
 "tracks" : {
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=track%3A%22Dude+Looks+Like+A+Lady+%22+artist%3A%22+Aerosmith%22&offset=0&limit=1&type=track",
    "items" : [ {
      "album" : {
        "album_type" : "album",
        "available_markets" : [ "CA", "MX", "US" ],
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/3XYqOJI1YlX40kJTdzFEzp"
        },
        "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/3XYqOJI1YlX40kJTdzFEzp",
        "id" : "3XYqOJI1YlX40kJTdzFEzp",
        "images" : [ {
          "height" : 640,
          "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/948208cdb26864468ee4320070cd10e6b580d852",
          "width" : 640
        }, {
          "height" : 300,
          "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/087aeee7ed7b7397f5cf5a4c90bc0532d7a3319c",
          "width" : 300
        }, {
          "height" : 64,
          "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/562e9fa179952065137a17b175b5bca0647d5f47",
          "width" : 64
        } ],
        "name" : "Permanent Vacation (Remastered)",
        "type" : "album",
        "uri" : "spotify:album:3XYqOJI1YlX40kJTdzFEzp"
      },
      "artists" : [ {
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/7Ey4PD4MYsKc5I2dolUwbH"
        },
        "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/7Ey4PD4MYsKc5I2dolUwbH",
        "id" : "7Ey4PD4MYsKc5I2dolUwbH",
        "name" : "Aerosmith",
        "type" : "artist",
        "uri" : "spotify:artist:7Ey4PD4MYsKc5I2dolUwbH"
      } ],
      "available_markets" : [ "CA", "MX", "US" ],
      "disc_number" : 1,
      "duration_ms" : 265773,
      "explicit" : false,
      "external_ids" : {
        "isrc" : "USIR10000454"
      },
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/track/6gQUbFwwdYXlKdmqRoWKJe"
      },
      "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/6gQUbFwwdYXlKdmqRoWKJe",
      "id" : "6gQUbFwwdYXlKdmqRoWKJe",
      "name" : "Dude (Looks Like A Lady)",
      "popularity" : 55,
      "preview_url" : "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/7d85766664041815e16b54eb014d3d120f883db8",
      "track_number" : 5,
      "type" : "track",
      "uri" : "spotify:track:6gQUbFwwdYXlKdmqRoWKJe"
    } ],
    "limit" : 1,
    "next" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=track%3A%22Dude+Looks+Like+A+Lady+%22+artist%3A%22+Aerosmith%22&offset=1&limit=1&type=track",
    "offset" : 0,
    "previous" : null,
    "total" : 7
  }
```

The only part that I actually need is the FINAL external_urls line that looks like this:

```
"external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/track/6gQUbFwwdYXlKdmqRoWKJe"
      },
```

As this is the one that contains the specific app.  I have done about 100 tries with the Web API, and this is the way it always appears.  So my question is HOW can I pull out JUST this one area?

Comment: If you want someone to show you how to do this, you should tag your question with either `swift` or `objective-c`, as appropriate. But, in answer to your question, you'd generally just parse this JSON and then grab the appropriate item. And to avoid dealing with `external_urls`, I might use the associated `href`, e.g. `json["tracks"]?["items"]?.last["href"]`.

Comment: I guess there is a missing `{` at the beginning and a `}` at the end. If yes, your question is not related to `NSData` but how to parse JSON, which has been so many times asked. JSON is just Dictionaries, Arrays, String and Numbers.